# Objective C: How can use two scrollview, one inside the another?

Tags: iphone

I have two scrollview, one scrollview inside another and I want to scroll my main scrollview content first after that only I want to scroll subview scroll

```
CGFloat scrollOffset = texscrl.contentOffset.y;    

if (scrollOffset == 0)
{
    //This condition will be true when scrollview will reach to bottom     
    self.ArtistScroll.scrollEnabled=YES;
    texscrl.scrollEnabled=YES;

}else
{
    self.ArtistScroll.scrollEnabled=NO;
texscrl.scrollEnabled=YES;
}
```

Here, am using content offset for this.. so can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the affect you describe by using a third scrollview to actually handle the touch gestures and manually set the contentOffset of the other scrollviews.

Here is how to achieve this for vertically scrolling content, which is I think what you are describing. In the code, `outerScrollView` is the main scrollview, `innerScrollView` is the sub-scrollview that is contained by the outer scrollview, and `trackingScrollView` is the third scrollview that only handles the touches - it has no content.

1. Create the three scrollviews such that `trackingScrollView` exactly covers `outerScrollView`. (I assume you will do this in XIB or storyboard so there is no code.)
2. Once your scrollviews have content (and whenever their contentSize or bounds change) you should set the contentSize of `trackingScrollView`:

   ```
   self.trackingScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.trackingScrollView.bounds.size.width,
                                                    self.outerScrollView.contentSize.height + self.innerScrollView.contentSize.height - self.innerScrollView.bounds.height);
   ```

   This makes the content height be that of `outerScrollView` plus the scrollable distance of `innerScrollView`, allowing `trackingScrollView` to scroll over the total travel distance of both scrollviews.
3. Delegate for `trackingScrollView` and implement `scrollViewDidScroll:`

   ```
   - (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
       if (scrollView == self.trackingScrollView) {
           CGFloat const offsetY = self.trackingScrollView.contentOffset.y;
           // Calculate the maximum outer scroll offset
           CGFloat const maxOuterOffsetY = self.outerScrollView.contentSize.height - self.outerScrollView.bounds.height;
           // Calculate the maximum inner scroll offset
           CGFloat const maxInnerOffsetY = self.innerScrollView.contentSize.height - self.innerScrollView.bounds.height;
           if (offsetY < maxOuterOffsetY) {
               // Scroll is within the outer scroll area or the top bounce zone
               self.outerScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, offsetY);
               self.innerScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
           } else if (offsetY < maxOuterOffsetY + maxInnerOffsetY) {
               // Scroll is within the inner scroll area
               self.outerScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, maxOuterOffsetY);
               self.innerScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, offsetY - maxOuterOffsetY);
           } else {
               // Scroll is within the bottom bounce zone
               self.outerScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, offsetY - maxInnerOffsetY);
               self.innerScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, maxInnerOffsetY);
           }
       } else {
           // Handle other scrollviews as required
       }
   }
   ```

   Effectively we divide the tracking scroll area into two parts. The top part controls the scrolling within the outer scrollview and the bottom part controls the inner scrollview.

   Assuming bounce is turned on (which generally it should be) we also need to handle scrolling outside the scroll area. We want the bounce to show on the outer scrollview so the top bounce is handled implicitly by the first conditional. However, the bottom bounce has to be handled explicitly by the third conditional, otherwise we would see the bounce on the inner scrollview.

To be clear, in this solution the two content scrollviews (`outerScrollView` and `innerScrollView`) do not receive any touches at all; all input is going to `trackingScrollView`. If you want input to subviews of the content scrollviews you will need a more advanced solution. I believe this can be done by putting `trackingScrollView` behind `outerScrollView`, removing `outerScrollView`'s gesture recognizers and replacing them with those from `trackingScrollView`. I have seen this technique presented in an old WWDC session on UIScrollView but I have not tried it myself.